# Spring-kafka offset commiting ways

Tags: java, spring, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

If I don't want to use auto-commmit mode - sping provides another ways to do it.

[spring-kafkfa/#committing-offsets](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#committing-offsets) give us following information about commiting offsets:

> `RECORD` - commit the offset when the listener returns after processing
>   the record.
>   `BATCH` - commit the offset when all the records returned by
>   the poll() have been processed.
>   `TIME` - commit the offset when all the
>   records returned by the poll() have been processed as long as the
>   ackTime since the last commit has been exceeded.
>   `COUNT` - commit the
>   offset when all the records returned by the poll() have been processed
>   as long as ackCount records have been received since the last commit.
>   `COUNT_TIME` - similar to TIME and COUNT but the commit is performed if
>   either condition is true.
>   `MANUAL` - the message listener is responsible
>   to acknowledge() the Acknowledgment; after which, the same semantics
>   as BATCH are applied.
>   `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` - commit the offset immediately
>   when the Acknowledgment.acknowledge() method is called by the
>   listener.

I have several questions:

`TIME` 
As I understand somewhere in the spring framework exists loop which do loop

```
while(true){
   data = consumer.poll();
   data.foreach(record->listener.listen(record))
}
```

How often poll happens?

Is time the only criteria for committing offset?
lets say poll returned a 100 records and when ackTime expired - only 60 records was processed?

I didn;t catch difference between `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` and `MANUAL`

Please, clarify these questons for me.

P.S.

As I understand Garry Russel answer foreach looks like this:

```
while(true){
   data = consumer.poll();
   data.foreach(record->new Thread(()->listener.listen(record)).start());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the version; the recent 1.3 version has a much simpler threading model, facilitated by [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread).

With that version, the listener is invoked on the caller thread; the next poll doesn't occur until all the current records are consumed. Aside from `RECORD` (and `MANUAL*`), the decision to commit is determined after all the records have been sent to the listener.

`MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` means just that; the offset is committed immediately when the user acks; with `MANUAL`, the manual offsets are committed after all records have been sent to the listener.

It's a bit more complicated with earlier versions; it is possible for one or two additional batches to be fetched, and the acks are performed before each poll so the offsets might be committed before all records in the first batch have been sent to the listener.

**EDIT**

Answering your comments below...

Yes; the threading was changed in 1.3. Before that, we had to keep polling the consumer to avoid the broker rebalancing the partitions. With <= 1.2, the `ConsumerRecords` are handed off the listener thread via a queue with depth of 1. The poller keeps polling until it can't fit any more `ConsumerRecords` in the queue; at which time, it `pause`s the consumer (so that subsequent polls return no records), but we have to still keep calling `poll` to avoid the rebalance. When the listener catches up, the consumer is `resume`d and messages start flowing again.

So, worst case is the container holds 3 sets of records - the one currently being processed by the listener, the one in the queue and the one we couldn't put in the queue. Any outstanding offset commits (manual or otherwise) are performed just before each poll.

> Will poll thread await processor thread?

No; we couldn't do that because that would cause a rebalance - it would have been the same as if we'd called the listener on the consumer thread.

KIP-62 was actually fixed in the 0.10.1.0 client, but we didn't change the threading until 1.3; it was a major simplification, thanks to KIP-62, and I would recommend using that version.

Comment: @Gart,  can you clarify a bit about "caller thread" ? What is it?

Comment: MANUAL_IMMEDIATE and MANUAL: For both cases client code must invoke Acknowledgment.acknowledge(). For MANUAL_IMMEDIATE - kafka server will be notified right now. for MANUAL - spring will collect acknowledgments while all records consumed by previous poll will not routed to listener. Is it correct?

Comment: With <= 1.2, there are two threads per consumer, one performing the `poll` (and `commit`s) and one to call the listener; the records are handed off to the second thread. This was needed to avoid undesired rebalancing due to a slow listener; if the listener is slow, the consumer thread eventually `pause` s the consumer until the listener catches up. Yes, correct, with manual, we collect all the manual acks and commit them before the next poll. `>consumed by previous poll will not routed to listener` - not sure what you mean by that; all records are sent to the listener.

Comment: Lets me ask from another side about MANUAL. I ask because I didn't understand your phrase *the manual offsets are committed after all records have been sent to the listener.* Ok there are 2 threads:  *poll thread* and *processor thread*.  Poll thread invoke poll and pass data to another thread? and what's next? Will poll thread await processor thread? processorThread.join() and only then commiit? Can next poll happen before previous poll records will be committed?

Comment: *slow listener* - can you explain this definition and why 2 threads help to resolve this issuue?

Comment: **With that version** what did you mean? >=1.3 ?

Comment: Gary, I partially understood. This scheme allow to poll and process in parallel. Commit for batch happens after the batch was hand of to the queue. Does it commit happens only for batch? Is it possible to commit only part of the batch?

Comment: As each record is processed by the listener (or manually ack'd), the offset is added to a map. The poller thread commits those offsets (depending on the ackmode) before each poll so, yes, with < 1.3 some offsets might be committed before all records in the poll have been processed. This does not apply with >= 1.3 since the listener is invoked on the same thread.

Comment: Ok. I understood. But why? just for simplification?

Comment: Also I don't understand how can I control how often poll will happen?

Comment: You can't - it's abstracted away by the container; if you need that level of control you can write your own consumer code and don't use a container.

Comment: But how to distinquish TIME, COUNT and COUNT_TIME? Lets we have time interval tuned as 5 secs. But processong of batch takes 7 sec. At this case how often poll will happen?

Comment: I depends; if there is reasonable message flow, the time, count, count_time are evaluated just before the poll. If there are no messages in the topic, the `pollTimeout` will affect how often the evaluations are made.